# Vue-meta: Cannot set property '$meta' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-meta

After installing vue-meta, there is an error in my browser console.

Why is this error showing up? Is it from my code or a bug? I am using `vue-meta@2.4.0` and Vue 3.

[image]

main.js

```
createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(VueMeta)
  .mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    "app-header": Header,
  },
};
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: "test meta data with vue",
      meta: [
        {
          vmid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content:
            "hello world, this is an example of adding a description with vueMeta",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Have you figured out the problem?

Comment: Not yet. But for the alternative solution i downgrade the vue version to vue 2.

Comment: Looks like, i have to do the same. :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228340/how-to-use-vue-3-meta-with-vue-js-3

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: Issue is being tracked here https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/628**

### tldr

From your syntax, (i.e., `createApp(App).use(router)`... etc.) it looks like you are using Vue3. The vue-meta plugin was developed for Vue2 and will not work with Vue3 until the developers create a corresponding version.

### Reason

In Vue3 the api has changed. The app object is passed into the install method of the plugin instead of the Vue constructor.

#### Vue 2 install def

`install: (Vue, options) => {}`

#### Vue 3 install def

`install: (app, options) => { }`

### There is a version 3

Located here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-3-meta
However - it seems the package is broken. It basically just installs vue-meta.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228340/how-to-use-vue-3-meta-with-vue-js-3

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the metaInfo property: [Doc](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta)

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: "test meta data with vue",
      metaInfo: [
        {
          vmid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content:
            "hello world, this is an example of adding a description with vueMeta",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: the error still showed up. should i use nuxt.js to use vue-meta? currently i just use vue

Comment: Could you update your post with the full error log ?