# How to use Vue 3 Meta with Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-meta

It seems that [Vue Meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) has been upgraded to handle Vue.js 3 with a new npm package called [`vue-3-meta`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-3-meta)

Before Vue.js 3, it was easy to use `vue-meta` by adding it to the Vue instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'
 
Vue.use(VueMeta, {
  // optional pluginOptions
  refreshOnceOnNavigation: true
})
```

However in Vue.js 3, there is no Vue instance; and instead you create the app by running `createApp` like such:

```
const app = createApp(App);
const router = createVueRouter();

app.use(router);
// need to make app use Vue-Meta here
```

I cannot find any documentation for `vue-3-meta`. `import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'` no longer works.

How do I import the `vue-3-meta` plugin properly and use it with `app` like in prior versions?

Comment: Thank you @Eldar. But I still don't understand where `metaManager` is coming from in `app.use(metaManager)`. Where is `metaManager` in App.vue?

Comment: For those coming here, I ended up not using vue-meta and used https://github.com/vueuse/head instead which works much better IMO.

Comment: Yeah, vueuse/head seems to be the proper successor. It is used in Nuxt 3.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### Disclaimer: [vue-meta v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-meta?activeTab=versions) is still in alpha!

This was the minimal implementation I needed to get started:

1. Update `vue-meta` to v3 (in package.json)

   ```
   - "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
   + "vue-meta": "^3.0.0-alpha.7",
   ```

   ...or with yarn:

   ```sh
   yarn add vue-meta@alpha
   ```
2. Add `metaManager` to Vue app

   ```
   import { createMetaManager } from 'vue-meta'

   const app = createApp(App)
     .use(router)
     .use(store)
     .use(createMetaManager()) // add this line

   await router.isReady()
   app.mount('#app')
   ```
3. Add `<metainfo>` to App.vue `<template>` (this is also where I set a "title template")

   ```
   <template>
     <metainfo>
       <template v-slot:title="{ content }">{{ content ? `${content} | SITE_NAME` : `SITE_NAME` }}</template>
     </metainfo>
     <header />
     <router-view />
     <footer />
   </template>
   ```
4. Set default meta in App.vue `<script>`
   *Vue 3 vanilla:*

   ```
   import { useMeta } from 'vue-meta'

   export default {
     setup () {
       useMeta({
         title: '',
         htmlAttrs: { lang: 'en', amp: true }
       })
     }
   }
   ```

   *or with `vue-class-component`:*

   ```
   import { setup, Vue } from 'vue-class-component'
   import { useMeta } from 'vue-meta'

   export default class App extends Vue {
     meta = setup(() => useMeta({
       title: '',
       htmlAttrs: { lang: 'en', amp: true }
     })
   }
   ```
5. Override meta in each component
   *Vue 3 vanilla:*

   ```
   import { useMeta } from 'vue-meta'

   export default {
     setup () {
       useMeta({ title: 'Some Page' })
     }
   }
   ```

   *or with `vue-class-component`:*

   ```
   import { computed } from '@vue/runtime-core'
   import { setup, Vue } from 'vue-class-component'
   import { useMeta } from 'vue-meta'

   export default class SomePage extends Vue {
     meta = setup(() => useMeta(
       computed(() => ({ title: this.something?.field ?? 'Default' })))
     )
   }
   ```

#### See also:

- ["Quick Usage" (vue-meta `next` branch)](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next#quick-usage)
- [Vue Router Example (vue-meta `next` branch)](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next/examples/vue-router)

Comment: I have managed to understand this so far. My question is that do we now define meta information like in the version 2 **(e.g meta : [ { }, { }, ], scripts: [ ] etc  )** or is this done another way.

Comment: @Nwaiwulsidore - The type [`MetaSource` hasn't been written yet](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/blob/next/src/types/index.ts), but there's 1 quite extensive example in Github; see: [App.ts](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/blob/next/examples/vue-router/App.ts), [Child.ts](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/blob/next/examples/vue-router/Child.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able gain some understanding from the github links. Another issue I want to understand is the behaviour between parent and child. In the older vue-meta, metadata from a child is merged with that of the parent except "vmid" is used. In this version, it seems that they are automatically overridden when you specify them in the child. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NwaiwuIsidore - I believe you are correct but I'm only using `v3` of `vue-meta` on a very simple project (so I can't confirm for certain). I haven't seen any ids in the examples; it looks like you just need to specify the same key. Seems v3 is smarter!

Comment: -. Thanks. It seems to be "smarter". I tried it out and it seems to work. "For now"

Comment: How did you manage to figure all this out without any proper documentation? I cannot find this stuff documented anywhere!

Comment: @volumeone - Mostly from the vue-router example in the GitHub repo (make sure you're looking at the code in the "next" branch. A little from the README (again "next" branch) & from reading any issue that looked to be for Vue 3. I still struggle with computed meta + vue-class-component.

Comment: FYI - The ["two title" issue](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/667) has just been fixed in `vue-meta@3.0.0-alpha.7` :)

Comment: Hello there, thank you very much for this answer! Cheers ;)

Comment: Hi, anyone knows whether `titleTemplate` is supported? And if I want to access `this` context inside `titleTemplate`, is this possible?

Comment: Looks like titleTemplate isn't supported/working for now as far I see.

Comment: is this still a working example? tried it with vue-meta@next and it didn't work

Comment: I haven't used `vue-meta` for some time. I've converted my answer to `community wiki` in case someone else wants to update it.

Comment: thanks for this helpful article. Good works.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous answers, I also needed to add a `transpileDependency` in my `vue.config.js`, as I was using `vue-cli`:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vue-meta']
}
```

Else, I would get the error:

```
error  in ./node_modules/vue-meta/dist/vue-meta.esm-browser.min.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:7170)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Thanks to this thread for pointing me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844988/3433137

Comment: I found a much better solution which was to drop vue-meta and use @vueuse/head https://github.com/vueuse/head

Answer (score 2):

`metaManager` is a [`MetaManager`](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/blob/498d747301617e4f73f1d1f663d613484ffc2367/dist/vue-meta.d.ts#L82) instance created from [`createMetaManager()`](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/blob/45704e0/src/manager.ts#L49) of `vue-meta`.

Based on the [*Vue 3 + Vue Router* example for `vue-meta`](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/blob/45704e0/src/manager.ts#L49), here's an example usage:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createMetaManager, defaultConfig, resolveOption, useMeta } from 'vue-meta'

const decisionMaker5000000 = resolveOption((prevValue, context) => {
  const { uid = 0 } = context.vm || {}
  if (!prevValue || prevValue < uid) {
    return uid
  }
})

const metaManager = createMetaManager({
  ...defaultConfig,
  esi: {
    group: true,
    namespaced: true,
    attributes: ['src', 'test', 'text']
  }
}, decisionMaker5000000)

useMeta(
  {
    og: {
      something: 'test'
    }
  },
  metaManager
)

createApp(App).use(metaManager).mount('#app')
```